# C# Сохранение на сервере больших файлов в потоке, передача через Httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

Подскажите, как правильно сделать сохранение больших файлов на сервере, к примеру, в 2гб.

Я использую код, который работает с небольшими файлами, а в случае с передачей файла в 2гб я получаю ошибку:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.IO.IOException: Stream was too long.
```

Так же пробовал сделать сохранение файлов отправкой частей файла на сервер, но запросов выходит слишком много, и скорость сохранения ниже, так как много подключений идёт к серверу.

Код для отправки файла:

```
 private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "https://localhost:5001/uploadfile";
            await SendFile(Path, url);

            textBox1.AppendText("Готово");
        }
        public async Task SendFile(string filePath, string url)
        {
            // Открываем файл для чтения
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Создаем объект HttpClient
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Создаем объект MultipartFormDataContent для передачи файла
                    using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        // Создаем объект StreamContent для передачи содержимого файла
                        using (StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
                        {
                            // Добавляем содержимое файла к объекту MultipartFormDataContent
                            content.Add(fileContent, "file", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));

                            // Отправляем запрос на сервер с помощью метода HTTP POST
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                            // Получаем ответ от сервера и проверяем его статусный код
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Файл успешно передан.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка при передаче файла.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Код для сохранения файла с потока:

```
public class FileController : Controller
    {
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = (long)4e+9)]
        [HttpPost("/uploadfile")]
       // [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
        {
            var maxRequestBodySize = (long)4e+9; // установка максимального размера тела запроса в байтах
            HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = maxRequestBodySize;
            // Получаем поток данных из запроса
            using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Считываем данные из потока по частям и сохраняем их в файл на сервере
            using var fileStream = new FileStream("test.rar", FileMode.Create);
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            await fileStream.FlushAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможно, тут вообще настройки сервера надо менять.

Comment: Не нужно писать в промежуточный `MemoryStream`. Пишите сразу в `FileStream`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это решило ошибку, спасибо, можете объяснить причину?

Comment: @Qwertiy установил атрибут `[RequestSizeLimit((long)1e+10)]` ограничение файлов в 10гб и удалил настройку `MaxRequestBodySize` тем самым проблема с лимитом решилась.

Comment: Но все таки передача через сокеты в разы быстрее, сравнил скорость передачи через http и сокеты.
Результат: https://ibb.co/z4b9QDP и озу сокеты меньше тратят

Comment: ОЗУ должно тратиться 0! Вернее, размер буфера (скажем, 64 кб). / Данные из потока от клиента сразу пишутся в файловый поток - откуда тут взяться потреблению памяти?

Comment: Локальные тесты в данном случае нерелевантны. Надо на живом серваке гонять. Плюс стоит понимать, что может случиться обрыв связи и придется качать заново. Докачку тоже стоит реализовать. И да, не надо ни в коем случае всасывать весь файл в оперативу, надо писать сразу на диск. Что такое "через сокеты", не понимаю. HTTP это тоже через сокеты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `откуда тут взяться потреблению памяти?` в студии порой проскакивает потребление памяти, возможно потому что смотрю работу в студии и @aepot прав нужно на серваке проверять потребление памяти.

Comment: @aepot `И да, не надо ни в коем случае всасывать весь файл в оперативу, надо писать сразу на диск.`
я беру данные из потока  таким способом, `while ((bytesRead = await Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)` то есть он не подходит для передачи нескольких файлов, если использовать  `Request.Form.Files` можно отправить любое количество файлов, но при работе с большими файлами они тратят много памяти для обработки. Как можно сделать чтобы передавать несколько файлов в рамках одного запроса  с помощью потоковой передачи, в гугле не могу найти ответ или не правильно ищу.

Comment: Не спрашивайте в комментариях, потому что комменты почти никто не видит. Редактируйте вопрос или создавайте новую тему с новым вопросом. | [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0), раздел Upload large files with streaming.